# Angular 6 Kendo Grid Field names with special characters

Tags: angular, typescript, kendo-ui, kendo-ui-grid

I am creating a dynamic grid in Kendo UI for Angular, the columns are created from
database columns, that are unfortunately in Swedish, that has the special characters å, ä and ö

for example, "ändradAv" (en: changedBy)

I am getting the error:

> Grid column field name 'ändradAv' does not look like a valid JavaScript identifier.
>                   Identifiers can contain only alphanumeric characters (including "$" or "_"), and may not start with a digit.
>                   Please use only valid identifier names to ensure error-free operation.

Everything is working properly and I am getting my columns as well as the data but I would like to get rid of this message.

Any suggestions?

Comment: How did you fix this?

Comment: I ended up parsing objects English before sending them to the front-end.